# jQuery missing ) after argument list, but the ( ) and closed and escaping quotes doesn't work

Tags: jquery

This has got to be simple. Why am I getting the error `missing ) after argument list` on this jQuery? All the `(` and `)` are closed. I tried escaping the quotes, too.

```
$(".state-button").on("click", function(e) {
if ($(".record.state:contains("AR")").length > 0) {   //Error on this line
      $(".record").toggleClass("display-block");
      e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: The `"` before `AR` closes the string that started with the `"` after `$(`. Either use `'` around the string instead, or escape the inner `"`. You also seem to have issues with closing `)` (you have it after the `}` on the `if`, but it should be on the `}` for the function).

Comment: Any half-decent IDE, such as VSCode, should be highlighting these errors for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the browser console. I tried escaping the quotes before, but now that appears to work Single quotes threw a syntax error, unexpected identifier "AR", expecting "," or ";". And yes, the } was out of place. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is proper

```
 $(".state-button").on("click", function(e) {
      if ($(".record.state:contains('AR')").length > 0) {
           $(".record").toggleClass("display-block");
           e.preventDefault();
      }
 }); <-- here
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I also had to use escaped double quotes around AR due to the error syntax error, unexpected identifier "AR", expecting "," or ";".  I'm echoing the script on a PHP page.